# SSRS Migration To a separate Network

Tags: migration, ssrs

We are building a new SSRS 2008R2 environment on a separate network.

How can I migrate the reports from our current network to the new network?

Can I backup the reports from the existing SSRS server and then put them in a location where the server on the new network can pick them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple backup and restore process, with the additional step of making sure you backup the Reporting Services key, so you can restore that as well.

A number of links on the internet, but this one is a step by step guide with screenshots,  much easier than trying to follow MSDN

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2692/migrating-sql-reporting-services-to-a-new-server-by-moving-the-reporting-services-databases

or if you are only talking a small number of reports and you want to change the credentials,etc you could simply import the .rdl definition files from SourceControl (hopefully :) )

If the 2 domains can authenticate with one another, then the current credentials will work. otherwise you will need to change the account used.

Answer (score 0):

Report Server Database can be backedup and migrated over to the new server in the new network which shouldn't be a trouble. Only problem I see is the Report Server URL, which is not mostly same as before. But, you should still have the same data as before after migration, but, with a different URL after migration.